How to detect constituent camera change when using builtInDualWideCamera?
I'm building an iOS camera app and need help with macro mode functionality. I want to:
Detect when the camera switches between wide and ultra-wide lenses (when it is set to builtInDualWideCamera) like the native iOS camera app does:

OR Program this behavior myself
Main questions:
Can I detect automatic lens switches through AVCaptureDevice/AVCaptureSession?
If not, what's the best way to detect when objects are very close to trigger a lens switch? I tried observing lensPosition, but it's not that reliable
Ideally I want to let the system do it and just get notified when the lens has changed.
How do I smoothly switch between wide/ultra-wide cameras in AVCaptureSession?
Looking for the most reliable approach to implement this macro mode feature.
